# Calculate unit value based multiple conditions and columns in Python

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, dataframe

Given a dataframe as follows:

```
   id    area  total_price unit
0   1  185.00        14840    m
1   2  215.00        15050    m
2   3  233.23        46799    d
3   4  122.00        17000    d
4   5  540.00        70000    d
5   6  415.00        78000    d
6   7  170.00        12270    m
7   8  410.00        30750    m
8   9  196.00        13787    m
9  10   55.00         3100    m
```

I would like to create a new column `unit_price` with numerical value based on the following conditions:

a. if `unit` is `m`, then `unit_price` is calculated by `total_price/area/30`;

b. if `unit` is `d`, then `unit_price` is calculated by `total_price/area`

This code works:

```
m = (df['unit'] == 'm')
df['unit_price'] = np.where(m, df['total_price']/df['area']/30, df['total_price']/df['area'])
```

I have used also the code below but it raises an error: `ValueError: Wrong number of items passed 256, placement implies 1`

```
def unit_price(x):
    if x['unit'] == 'm':
        return x['total_price']/x['area']/30
    if x['unit'] == 'd':
        return x['total_price']/x['area']

df['unit_price'] = df.apply(unit_price, axis = 1)
```

Anyone know why I get this error, and how to fix it? Thanks.

Comment: Your `np.where` is perfectly fine and much better than your `apply`. Why do you have to go for `apply`. Also should be `return x['total_price']/x['area']` in your function.

Comment: At this case, you are right, but I'm considering if we have `unit` more than `m` and `d`.

Comment: Then do a `np.select`.

Comment: By the way, the updated `unit_price` function should work fine with `apply`.

Comment: Sorry, do you mind show me with this example using `np.select`?

Comment: Is it obliged to use `else` in the end of `if-else` function? or `if-if` is also ok?

Comment: Since you are returning inside the `if` condition, there's no point to use `else` or `elif`. Also see my answer below for `np.select` and another approach.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With `np.select` you can do:

```
c1, c2 = df['unit']=='m', df['unit']=='d'

df['unit_price'] = np.select((c1,c2), 
                             (df['total_price']/df['area']/30, df['total_price']/df['area']),
                             np.nan)
```

However, with this case, it's better to do a map:

```
units = {'m':30, 'd':1, 'y':365}

df['unit_price'] = df['total_price']/df['area'] / df['unit'].map(units)
```

Output:

```
   id    area  total_price unit  unit_price
0   1  185.00        14840    m    2.673874
1   2  215.00        15050    m    2.333333
2   3  233.23        46799    d  200.656005
3   4  122.00        17000    d  139.344262
4   5  540.00        70000    d  129.629630
5   6  415.00        78000    d  187.951807
6   7  170.00        12270    m    2.405882
7   8  410.00        30750    m    2.500000
8   9  196.00        13787    m    2.344728
9  10   55.00         3100    m    1.878788
```

Comment: `np.select` and `map` approaches are pretty cool, thanks a lot for sharing.